# Is there any way to replace a function in a library?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I work with a library which defines its internal division operator for a scripting language. Unfortunately it does not zero-check the divisor. Which leads to lot of headaches. I know the signature of the operator.

`double ScriptClass::Divide(double&, double&);`

Sadly it isn't even a C function. Is there any way I could make my application use my own `Divide` function instead of `ScriptClass::Divide` function?

EDIT:
     I was aware of `dlopen(NULL,..)` and replacing "C" functions with user defined ones. Can this be done for class member functions (Without resorting to using mangled names)?

Comment: Create your own function, and use it? You could even have your function call `ScriptClass::Divide`, but wrap it in a zero-check.

Comment: @birryree: I'd have done it myself if it were that simple :D. The `ScriptClass` creates its inner structure by parsing a script. 99% of all that code I don't want to write again. I just want to replace the division fucntion.

Comment: I knew I was missing something in this problem.

Comment: Considering it's script input, couldn't you fix it on the script side? Rewrite the script, replacing all occurances of `(a/b)` by `(a==0?NaN:a/b)` (or whatever syntax the script may have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking it's up to the programmer, not the underlying divide operator to prevent division by zero. If you're dividing by zero a lot that seems to indicate a possible flaw in the algorithm being used. Consider reworking the algorithm, or if that's not an option, guard calls to divide with a zero check. You could even do that inside a `protected_divide` type function.

All that being said, assuming that since it looks like a C++ function you have a C++ library compiled with all the same options you're using to build your application so name mangling matches you might be able to redefine the function into a `.so` and use `LD_PRELOAD` to force it to load. If you link statically, I *think* you can create the function into your own `.o` file and linking that prior to the library itself will cause the linker to pick up your version.

Comment: I am linking the library statically. I tried the second method you mentioned and the linker threw a 'multiple definition' error at me as it should. Unless I can tell the linker to use the first definition it encounters and discard all others, I can't use that. The first method cannot be used because of so many restrictions I don't want to mention here. I'd like a solution that fits in the binary.

Answer (score 4):

Various linkers and dynamic linker implementations will provide something that looks like a solution to this, as others have mentioned.

However, if you redefine one C++ function using any of those features (GNU ld's --wrap, ld.so's LD_PRELOAD, etc.), **you are violating the one-definition rule** and are thus invoking undefined behaviour.

While compiling your library, the compiler is allowed to inline the function in question in any way that it sees fit, which means that your redefinition of the function might not be invoked in all cases.

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
    void bar();
};

void A::foo()
{
    std::cout << "Old version.\n";
}

void A::bar()
{
   foo();
}
```

GCC 4.5, when invoked with -O3, will actually decide to inline the definition of foo() into bar(). If you somehow made your linker replace this definition of A::foo() with a definition of your own, A::bar() would *still* output the string "Old version.\n".

So, in a word: don't.

Comment: That's a good point, but what are your other options? I'm not sure "don't" is the most helpful response, since that's exactly what the OP has been doing until now. If it was working for him, or if he had any easier way of doing it -- wouldn't he still be doing that, instead? Rather than fiddling about with this sort of stuff? :)

Comment: +1 anyway since it occurs to me that if the function is just some little thing that's only called once (which for a divide function in a script interpreter could easily be the case) then this could well happen.

Comment: I honestly couldn't think of a more helpful answer than "don't". Now that I think of it, I might add that there might be a resonable chance of succeeding if the function in question is virtual. It would still technically be undefined behaviour, but it takes a very smart optimizer to ever inline a virtual function, so it probably won't happen. So if the function is virtual and you cannot just derive from the class and override it, it might be worth a try.

Comment: No, the function is not virtual. If it were, I'd have no problems.

Answer (score 3):

LD_PRELOAD is your friend. As an example, see:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090130063728/http://ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-glibc.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no getting away from the mangled names, I don't think, but you can use ld's `--wrap` option to cause a particular function to be given a new name based on its old name. You can then write a new version of it, and forward to the old version too if you like.

Quick overview here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

I've used this in the past to hook into `malloc` (etc.) without having to recompile the runtime library, though this wasn't on Linux (it was an embedded thing with no runtime loading). I didn't use it to wrap C++ functions, but if you can handle the C++ calling convention somehow, and you can create a function with the original function's mangled name, and get the compiler to accept a call to a function that has some ugly name with funny chars in it... I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just short Q,
Cant you just wrap the class with your own code?
It'll be some headache at the start but after than you can simplify a lot of functions.

(Or even just wrap the function with a macro)

Comment: I am not using the function as I keep saying :). I want to change the function that something else uses because it makes things come crashing down. If I were using the function there'd be no problem.